# How to update Counter's value inside a Label of another class?

Tags: swift, timer, uikit

I have a counting-upward object in `StopWatch` class and a label showing its value in `ViewController` class. I used `@Published` and `@ObservedObject` property wrappers for sharing and observing `counter`'s value.

How could I automatically update counter's value in a label?

`ViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @ObservedObject var stopWatch = StopWatch()
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        label.text = "\(self.stopWatch.counter)"
    }

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) { self.stopWatch.start() }
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) { self.stopWatch.stop() }
}
```

`StopWatch.swift`

```
class StopWatch: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var counter: Int = 0
    var timer = Timer()
    
    func start() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, 
                                                   repeats: true) { _ in
            self.counter += 1
        }
    }
    func stop() {
        self.timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Incoherent. You have tagged and imported SwiftUI and introduced ObservableObject as if this _were_ SwiftUI, but in fact this pure UIKit and you should not be using ObservableObject at all. Just use an ordinary object and set up your own publish and subscribe architecture if you want the label to update reactively.

Comment: Either that or throw away the view controller and adopt SwiftUI for real. In that case the updating of a Text display can be trivially automatic from the ObservableObject.

Comment: One final point: you wrote "a label storing its value"; but a label does not "store" a value. It displays or reflects a value. Never treat interface as data storage, not even as a passing figure of speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ObservedObject` works only inside SwiftUI view. In this case it is possible to observe published property directly via Publisher, like

```
import Combine
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stopWatch = StopWatch()
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cancellable = stopWatch.$counter.sink { [weak self] newValue in
            self?.label.text = "\(newValue)"
        }
    }

// ... other code
```